# cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.mailgun.net port 443

Tags: guzzle, mailgun

I'm trying mailgun service to send mails with Laravel 5.2.29 using the driver (guzzlehttp/guzzle) in the sandbox domain first. But after confire de domain, and the API key I get alway the error:
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.mailgun.net port 443

Any idea please?

regards

Comment: From time to time, that happens to me to, but its only temporary. So I catch the error and after some time a try it again and it ussualy works.  Btw. calling mailgun too many times at once? Does this happen all the time?